# create a wrapper controller for all calls to web services in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns

I am working to creating a wrapper for my existing application controllers.

For example, i have two controllers accepting similar set of parameters and similar methods.

Code is as below

```
class EmployeeController < ApplicationController

  def list
  end

end


class DepartmentController < ApplicationController

  def list
  end

end
```

end point would be **http://localhost:3000/employee/list**
&
**http://localhost:3000/department/list**

**What is the best way to create wrapper controller and invoke either of the controllers action.**

is this way correct, where we check certain parameters and create objects accordingly or are there better ways to do it

```
class WrapperController < ApplicationController


  def list
    if params["which"].eql?("employee")
      data = EmployeeController.new(params).create
    else
      data = DepartmentController.new(params).label
    end

  end
end
```

end point would be http://localhost:3000/wrapper/list

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there particular reason you want/need to do this?

Comment: Helle Iceman, thanks for your reply, i want to expose a generic API to return list or implement other functionality

Comment: I don't recommend a generic controller... it is the recipe to a nightmare of abstractions or you would end having a lot of IF conditions increasing the complexity of actions just to not repeat them, as they probably don't do exactly the same thing on each plase is used... 

Here you can see a post about the abstraction subject... https://www.sandimetz.com/blog/2016/1/20/the-wrong-abstraction

Comment: Hello cefigueiredo, thanks for the link, but can you tell what is the standard way to implement it

Comment: you need a service objects I think..

Comment: Having a generic API call that does 2 things would not be RESTful, and it would violate the rule of "do one thing and do it well"
Do you want a client to be able to hit `/wrapper/list` and it could do two different things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `WrapperController` sounds like a really bad idea. Especially instantiating another controller and calling a method on it. I don't recall seeing such pattern anywhere. Rails does a lot of magic around request/response cycle, so calling another controller will most likely break something later on. I am just guessing that cookies may not work, or rendering can be broken etc.

Anyway, what you probably want is better organise your business logic inside Rails application. As a starting point I strongly recommend reading [this article](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/). Based on limited information from your question it is hard to give a good answer for your particular case.

For example, you can implement a query object:

```
class EmployeesQuery
  def initialize(params)
    # initialize some internal variables
  end

  def list
    # write code for fetching employees based on passed params
  end
end

class DepartmentsQuery
  def initialize(params)
    # initialize some internal variables
  end

  def list
    # write code for fetching employees based on passed params
  end
end

class QueryFactory
  QUERIES = {
    "employee" => EmployeeQuery,
    "department" => DepartmentQuery
  }

  get self.get_query(resource)
    QUERIES[resource] || raise("Some exception")
  end
end
```

Now you can create a `ListsController`:

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    data = QueryFactory.get_query(params[:which]).list
    # render specific view based on requested resource
    # and rescue possible exception from get_query method
  end
end
```

And in `config/routes.rb`:

```
get "/:which/list" => "lists#index"
```

This can be later extended with more resources and having separate query objects for each will make it more maintainable. The only problematic thing is how to render generated results, but you can use similar pattern for selecting correct template to render.

If you want to have similar pattern for creating objects, you should look at service object pattern. It is described in linked article.

Also you can kind solve your problem with much simpler way, just by changing `config/routes.rb` a little bit.

```
get "/:controller/list", to: :list
```

It will route `/employee/list` to `EmployeeController` and `/department/list` to `DepartmentController`. And basically it will route to any valid controller, so maybe you want to tweak it a little bit and add some restrictions.

Hope that helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Why shouldn't we just forward it with same request

```
class WrapperController < ApplicationController


  def list
    if params["which"].eql?("employee")
      controller = EmployeeController.new
    else
      controller = DepartmentController.new
    end
    controller.request = request
    controller.response = response
    controller.list

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have this with Application Controller, that's why its the parent controller. The standard way would be to add a before_action in ApplicationController that performs the check and then redirects to the proper controller.

```
class ApplicationController

    before_action :check_emp_or_dept

    def check_emp_or_dept
        if employee_params.fetch("which", "").eql?("employee")
            @employee = Employee.find employee_params['id'] 
            redirect_to @employee
        else
            @department = Department.find department_params['id']
            redirect_to @department
        end
    end

  protected
    # handle strong params according to what your model requires
    def department_params
      params.require(:department).permit(:param1, :param2)
    end

    # handle strong params according to what your model requires
    def employee_params
        params.require(:department).permit(:param1, :param2)
    end

end
```

Note this code above will need to be reworked to your specific setup for strong params. I would argue that it's not a good idea to create Employees/Departments blindly based on the passed params, although you can easily change the find methods above to "find_or_create_by" methods if you so choose.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this easily in routing (i.e. `routes.rb` file) using constraints:

```
get '/wrapper/list', to: 'employee#list', 
  constraints: lambda { |request| 
    request.query_parameters["which"] == "employee"
  }
get '/wrapper/list', to: 'department#list', 
  constraints: lambda { |request|
    request.query_parameters["which"] != "employee"
  }
```

Comment: Hello Esse, thanks for your reply. What if there are n number of multiple controller in addition to Employee, Department. Is this the standard approach? can you point me to some documentation.

Comment: here is the documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints if you need to provided multiple controlers like this I would recommend creating constraint object and moving this logic there. And test it of course ;)